# How to place one element on top of another relative to screen size?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a gauge I have created in xaml (see picture below). The initial issue I had is that there is no way to display negative number in the gauge via my API, so I want to be able to just put a '-' next to the number I have in the middle of the gauge with a `label`. I have been able to do this in xaml with a `Grid` layout below.

My issue is that if the screen is a different size, the gauge size will change, and the margin of the label will no longer fit to the middle of the gauge. How can I put one element on top of another relative to the scaled size. For example, I know in css you can just use percentages (move one element to have a left margin of 50% of the other element), but not sure what to do in xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.Summary"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Maui"
             xmlns:gvm="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1.VM;assembly=CellularSignal1"
             Title="Summary">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <gvm:SummaryViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="-" FontSize="80" TextColor="Red" Margin="290 140"/>
            <lvc:PieChart VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Series="{Binding Series}"
                InitialRotation="-225"
                MaxAngle="270"
                Total="100">
            </lvc:PieChart>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: instead of `Margin`, use `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` to set the `Label` in the center of the `Grid`

Comment: I was using 50% as an example. While this is a good idea, I don't need centered. As you can see from the picture if '-' is centered, it will not be in the same location - it will appear on top of the 10

Comment: Then you probably need to calculate the offset in code.  I don’t think you can do it with just XAML

Comment: I'm fine with doing that. Not sure how to get the grid width though, when I request the width I get -1;

Comment: That will happen if you do it before the layout calc is complete

Comment: I've given seconds for the layout to calc, so hard to believe it hasn't had enough time.

Comment: Man, I do not know what witchcraft you are trying to do. All logic suggest that this symbol "-" should be part of the chart. If you cannot make it the right way, just center "-[space][space][space]"

Comment: If you want to keep the position in the middle, you can try to use the `AbsoluteLayout`.

Comment: @H.A.H Yea, it's an API I want to use which takes a lot of whitchcraft to get to work with negative numbers.